# Get data in custom Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this custom Jquery Plugin just to append text in input

```
<input id="txtName" value="My name is " />

<button id="btnGetData">Say what?</button>
```

and this is from my plugin

```
$.fn.AppendMe = function(strToAppnd)
{
    var newTxt = this.val() + strToAppnd;
    this.val(newTxt);

    function GetData()
    {    
        return newTxt;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var finalForm = $('#txtName').AppendMe('Enteng');

    $('#btnGetData').click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var result = finalForm.GetData();

            alert(result);
        });
});
```

and i want to get the result. How to put public method from instantiated plugin?

i want to alert the result when i click a button

[Click here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgdagpin/yp43dekz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of this about your code, before the answer:

- You should keep capital first letter only for function that designed to be called as constructor.
- Your plugin should return the jQuery object, so that it remains chainable.

Here is one working solution:

```
$.fn.appendMe = function(strToAppnd)
{
    var newTxt = this.val() + strToAppnd;
    this.val(newTxt);

    this.getData = function getData()
    {    
        return newTxt;
    }
    return this;
}

$(document).ready(function (){
    var finalForm = $('#txtName').appendMe('Enteng');

    $('#btnGetData').click(function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var result = finalForm.getData();

            alert(result);
        });
});
```

[JSFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/yp43dekz/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps simply return the newTxt.

```
$.fn.AppendMe = function(strToAppnd)
{
    var newTxt = this.val() + strToAppnd;
    this.val(newTxt);

    return newTxt;
}

...

var finalForm = $('#txtName').AppendMe('Enteng'); // Actually contains the whole string from the input
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yp43dekz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin needs a return value.

Since you are calling the `.GetData()` method, I'd assume you want to return an object with the `.GetData()` method:

```
$.fn.AppendMe = function(strToAppnd)
{
    var newTxt = this.val() + strToAppnd;
    this.val(newTxt);
    return {
        GetData: function(){
            return newTxt;   
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Your plugin isn't instantiated. Your plugin is a method, method's aren't instantiated.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yp43dekz/3/)

Comment: @VincentDagpin Once you know ;) -- Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery plugins should return the current context (the current jQuery collection) to support [chaining](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#chaining). Futhermore you should [minimize the plugin footprint](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#minimizing-plugin-footprint). So I would not recommend to use an extra `GetData` function in the `$.fn` namespace.

I would suggest to write the plugin like this:

```
$.fn.AppendMe = function(strToAppnd)
{
    var newTxt = this.val() + strToAppnd;
    this.val(newTxt);
    // return the jQuery collection to support chaining
    return this;
}
```

Now you can use the plugin like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $finalForm = $('#txtName').AppendMe('Enteng');

    $('#btnGetData').click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var result = $finalForm.val();

            alert(result);
        });
});
```